# Loading a video in OpenCV in Python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm desperately attempting to load a video file in OpenCV in Python (on OSX Lion)
 using the following code:

```
> import cv
> capture = cv.CaptureFromFile("in.avi")
```

However, i only get the following warning:

```
> WARNING: Couldn't read movie file in.avi
```

There is no explanation as to what the problem is (it can't find the file, wrong codec, etc). As far as Google is concerned I'm the only one in the universe getting this exact message in OpenCV.

I've read the 'codec compatibility docs' [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VideoCodecs) and made sure to convert the video to the correct codec using **mencode**, but it still doesn't work.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried using the full path? if the in.avi isn't in the current working directory of the script, then that will be a problem the way it is written.

Comment: That was exactly it! In my case it needed to be: /Users/lauge/Desktop/video.mov

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answer: See my comment - Wrong path.

Comment: Same here. I don't get it why this method needs absolute path.

Comment: i think this is a problem with the mac os version... the same code runs perfectly on my ubuntu machine but crashes on my macbook

Comment: Ideally someone could commit a patch and add

#import os
...
path = os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser(path))

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, support home folders and replace relative paths to absolute ones using

```
#import os
...
path = os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser(path))
```